# Optimal list traversion algorithm

Tags: algorithm, list, language-agnostic, traversal

I have a huge text corpus (10^8 words) for which I want to do a lot of different types of text analysis. One of these analyses is directly related to the text characters.

After filtering out unimportant characters like spaces, punctuation marks, etc, I need to find an optimal way to see whether letters are vowels or consonants (with some subdivisions). There are also some letters which shouldn't occur, like 'w' and 'j'.

```
vowels = ['e','a','o','y']
consonants = ['t','s','r','n','m','c','l','p','d','q','b','g','f','h','k']
semivowels = ['i', 'u']
heavyMakers = ['x','z']
```

These lists are already sorted internally by relative frequencies on a much smaller corpus, i.e. 'e' is more prevalent than 'a', 'n' is more prevalent than 'm', etc.

I want to know which lists to traverse first in order to achieve optimal search strength, and whether or not a significant performance hit is to be expected if I choose the wrong order.

I imagine the exact frequency tables can be useful, too:

All vowels: 3839

```
e   1689    vowel
a   1376    vowel
o   736     vowel
y   38      vowel
```

All consonants: 7359

```
t   1171    consonant
s   1044    consonant
r   960     consonant
n   824     consonant
m   729     consonant
c   542     consonant
l   457     consonant
p   373     consonant
d   331     consonant
q   259     consonant
b   210     consonant
g   193     consonant
f   143     consonant
h   124     consonant
k   1       consonant
```

All semivowels: 2671

```
i   1345    semivowel
u   1327    semivowel
```

All heavyMakers: 59

```
x   58      heavyMaker
z   1       heavyMaker
```

From the data it's obvious that heavyMakers should go last, but I'm not sure about the order vowels - semivowels - consonants. Consonants are the most likely hit, but also the longest list by far if this test fails. Vowels are more likely to hit than semivowels, but the list is longer (though not dramatically so).

I am willing to split the consonant lists between high-frequency and low-frequency characters, but my lists can under no circumstances be merged. Also, I repeat: I'm not sure any 'improvements' will have a dramatic performance impact.

The language I use is Python, but I'm fairly sure this is a language-agnostic algorithm question.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use a dict like `{'e': 'vowel', 'a': 'vowel', ..., 't': 'consonant', ..., 'z': 'heavyMaker'}`?

Comment: Moreover, provided you have only English letters, you could even use an array, for example in C++ `LetterType letterTypes[256]` or even `LetterType letterTypes[26]` where `LetterType` is an enum/string/whatever suits you better

Comment: @DavidEisenstat this would require a lot of refactoring, but you're probably right that it will probably be the most performant solution. Seems like there was a tiny box I was thinking in :-)